# Access GlusterFS file system in spring boot application

Tags: java, spring, nfs, fuse, glusterfs

I am new to GlusterFS. After watching this video https://youtu.be/IGEtVYh0C2o , I have a big picture of how the GlusterFS servers are working. I understand a client machine can access a volume.

Currently, I am developing a spring boot application in Java, and I would like to access the glusterfs volume to perform some read/write/delete/transfer file operations.

**My question is how to access GlusterFS in a Java/Spring boot application?**

**Is there any other library(except for the following one) or approach to acting as the client of GlusterFS in a java/spring boot application?**

I found a library here: https://github.com/gluster/glusterfs-java-filesystem .
However, it has not been updated for 6 years. I wonder if it still supports the latest version of GlusterFS, the latest release is v10.1 (https://docs.gluster.org/en/latest/release-notes/#glusterfs-selinux-release-notes)

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Glusterfs clients can be setup [relatively easy](https://docs.gluster.org/en/main/Administrator-Guide/Setting-Up-Clients/) on OS level, and mounted volumes look and function like any other volume.

Your code will then do read/write/delete/transfer file operations on mounted volume.